# How to get values from a URL using hash and split

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a url like this

```
http://localhost:9000/index.html#/acceptRequest?screen_name=kailash&rf=FIN1
```

Here I want to take FIN1 from the url and store it in another variable
I am using doing this in angularjs

I have made a function like this

```
function getUrlVars()
{ 
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        console.log(hash[1]);
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Here the console line hash[1] prints kailash FIN1.I only need the FIN1 to be stored and just print it in the console.How to make that happen?...
Anyway thanks in advance...

Comment: I just said that in case if i am not being specific that's all

Comment: Is that URL for your Angular app?

Comment: thats a strange place to see query parameters.. is there a reason they arent at the end of your `.html`? what is appending them? there may be a better way to handle the use of them

Comment: It's actually developed inside play framework and mostly i used used angular functions and their attributes...so its kind of an angular app..yeah

Answer (score 2):

If the URL is for a resource in your Angular app, you can simply inject the `$location` service and use

```
var anotherVariable = $location.search().rf
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the url parameter you need. You just have to call it and tell what value you need.

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return results[1] || 0;
    }
};
```

Use it like

```
var yourVariable= getUrlParameter("rf");
```

It will return the value of rf.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you soon...thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution for you.In core `Javascript`.

```js
var url = "http://localhost:9000/index.html#/acceptRequestscreen_name=kailash&rf=FIN1";
var test = url.lastIndexOf('=');

var r = url.slice(test+1);
alert(r);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help...But how to take the url value fro the browser itself  and store in the url variable here instead of manually mentioning it.

Comment: Then you want to get `rf=FIN1` as a variable value pair.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i got an answer

we just have to store the return value of that function to a variable like this

```
var urlParams = getUrlVars();
```

then all we need to do is to

```
console.log(urlParams['rf']);
```

thats it...

anyway you guys have been a great help... Thank you for responding.